# Difference in quantization regarding transpose_conv2d / conv2d

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, transpose-convolution

I'm trying to implement a transpose_conv2d function using padding/dilation of the input and calling a regular conv2d function. My approach is calculating the new input shape, padding and dilating the original input into new shape and calling regular conv2d with the same accumulator-scale, offset etc.
background: my task is to implement the workflow and codegen of a transposed_conv2d layer in ApacheTVM on gemmini accelerator. Codegen works for now, but the 'net' seems to provide wrong output.
Dataflow is bare minimum: qnn.conv2d_transpose -> nn.bias_add -> qnn.requantize 
Codegen is based on regular conv2d (which is proven to work) while changing output shape, function calls etc.

Is there a difference in the way quantization works regarding transposed/regular convolutions? I'm using the TFLite frontend with int8 weights, inputs and outputs.

Gemmini convolutions fuse qnn.conv2d, nn.bias_add and qnn.requantize into a single function (see: [Gemmini - A note about quantization](https://discuss.tvm.apache.org/t/presenting-the-generation-of-code-for-the-gemmini-accelerator/14107#a-note-about-quantization-5)). But since calculating the new bias should not be affected by padding/dilation, I don't suspect the issue here.

Any ideas appreciated. Thanks!